# rewrite a correlated subqueries in ef core 2.1

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

Is there a way i can rewrite this query so it is not a correlated subqueries ?

```
var query = (from o in dbcontext.Orders
                             let lastStatus = o.OrderStatus.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault()
                             where lastStatus.OrderId != 1
                             select new { o.Name, lastStatus.Id }
                             ).ToList();
```

This resulted in:

```
 SELECT [o].[Name], (
          SELECT TOP(1) [x0].[Id]
          FROM [OrderStatus] AS [x0]
          WHERE ([x0].[OrderId] = [o].[Id]) AND ([o].[Id] = [x0].[OrderId])
          ORDER BY [x0].[CreatedDate] DESC
      ) AS [Id]
      FROM [Orders] AS [o]
      WHERE (
          SELECT TOP(1) [x].[OrderId]
          FROM [OrderStatus] AS [x]
          WHERE ([x].[OrderId] = [o].[Id]) AND ([o].[Id] = [x].[OrderId])
          ORDER BY [x].[CreatedDate] DESC
      ) <> 1
```

I have tried to do a join on a subquery but EF 2.1 is doing weird things... not what I expected;

```
     var query = (from o in dbcontext.Orders
                     join lastStat in (from os in dbcontext.OrderStatus
                                       orderby os.CreatedDate descending
                                       select new { os }
                                       ) on o.Id equals lastStat.os.OrderId
                     where lastStat.os.StatusId != 1
                     select new { o.Name, lastStat.os.StatusId }).ToList();
```

Comment: What are you actually expecting (business-wise)? All the orders along with the name of their last status OR all the orders along with all their statuses order by CreatedDate descending? The first LINQ suggests the first thing and the last query the second.

Comment: I am expecting all the order with their last status.  Because, for one order you have many statuses, the query above is just a simple repetition of a large query. maybe I should just use the join

Comment: a simple JOIN is not what you want, because it would multiply all orders with found statuses. I have provided a solution that uses `GroupBy`. SQL Server allows a simpler form by using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) AS RowNo` followed by `RowNo = 1`, but I do not know how to achieve it, so I would stick to classic grouping.

Comment: In the first LINQ query `Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id)` is redundant - this filter (and the join) is implied from the navigation property. Also `where lastStatus.OrderId != 1` seems to be wrong - in the second query you use `StatusId != 1`. Aside from that, there is no way to avoid the subquery. What is the problem with the EF generated SQL query - performance? Because normally when you use ORM you don't care about generated SQL.

Comment: @IvanStoev, Yeah the problem is the performance, we need to materialize about 5k row (due to the N+1 problem) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF6 replacing

```
let x = (...).FirstOrDefault()
```

with

```
from x in (...).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

usually generates better SQL.

So normally I would suggest

```
var query = (from o in db.Set<Order>()
             from lastStatus in o.OrderStatus
                 .OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedDate)
                 .Take(1)
             where lastStatus.Id != 1
             select new { o.Name, StatusId = lastStatus.Id }
            ).ToList();
```

(no need of `DefaultIfEmpty` (left join) because the `where` condition will turn it to inner join anyway).

Unfortunately currently (EF Core 2.1.4) there is a translation issue so the above leads to client evaluation.

The current workaround is to replace the navigation property accessor `o.OrderStatus` with correlated subquery:

```
var query = (from o in db.Set<Order>()
             from lastStatus in db.Set<OrderStatus>()
                 .Where(s => o.Id == s.OrderId)
                 .OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedDate)
                 .Take(1)
             where lastStatus.Id != 1
             select new { o.Name, StatusId = lastStatus.Id }
            ).ToList();
```

which produces the following SQL for SqlServer database (lateral join):

```sql
  SELECT [o].[Name], [t].[Id] AS [StatusId]
  FROM [Orders] AS [o]
  CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP(1) [s].*
      FROM [OrderStatus] AS [s]
      WHERE [s].[OrderId] = [o].[Id]
      ORDER BY [s].[CreatedDate] DESC
  ) AS [t]
  WHERE [t].[Id] <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are actually fetching all the `Order`s, but only a portion of them (a page or a batch for processing).

In this case, it might be better to split it in two queries (not tested though):

```
var orders = dbcontext.Orders.Where(o => /* some filter logic */);
var orderIds = orders.Select(o => o.OrderId).ToList();

// get status for latest change - this should query OrderStatus only
var statusNameMap = dbContext.OrderStatus
   .Where(os => orderIds.Contains(Id))
   .GroupBy(os => os.OrderId)
   .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(grp => grp.CreatedDate).First())
   .ToDictionary(os => os.OrderId, os => os.StatusId);

// aggregate the results
// the orders might fetch only the needed columns to have less data on the wire
var result = orders.
    .ToList()
    .Select(o => new { o.Name, statusNameMap[o.OrderId] });
```

I do not think the queries will be nicer, but it might be easier to understand what is going on here.

If you really have to process all `Order`s and you have many of them (or many `Status`es), you might consider maintaining a `LastStatusId` column directly in `Order` table (this should be updated whenever a status is changed).